# To Convert an unstructured string to 2d array om PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have parsed some data from a file into a string variable,

```
 CPU    NFS   CIFS   HTTP   Total     Net   kB/s     HDD   kB/s     SSD   kB/s    Tape   kB/s  Cache  Cache    CP  CP   HDD   SSD   OTHER    FCP  iSCSI     FCP   kB/s   iSCSI   kB/s
                                   in    out    read  write    read  write    read  write    age    hit  time  ty  util  util                            in    out      in    out
 65%      0      0      0   11357   97020   2846       0 156160       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   45%    0%       3      0  11354       0      0   92987      0
 67%      0      0      0   11761  100535   2943     511 161119       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   43%    0%       0      0  11761       0      0   96397      0
 66%      0      0      0   11911  101736   2984     276 151088       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :v   48%    0%       0      0  11911       0      0   97534      0
 56%      0      0      0   12026  102664   3094      36     24       0      0       0      0   >60    100%    1%  :     2%    0%      11      0  12015       0      0   98419      0
 81%      0      0      0   10023   85660   2317    1964 198416       0      0       0      0   >60    100%   83%  Ff   60%    0%       0      0  10023       0      0   82117      0
 67%      0      0      0   11914  101825   2993     336 152883       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   55%    0%       0      0  11914       0      0   97625      0
 67%      0      0      0   11526   98491   2869     256 151040       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   51%    0%       0      0  11526       0      0   94388      0
 66%      0      0      0   11589   99011   2931       0 143225       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   51%    0%       0      0  11589       0      0   94949      0
 57%      0      0      0   11869  101355   3032      56  20544       0      0       0      0   >60    100%   26%  :    10%    0%       7      0  11862       0      0   97182      0
 76%      0      0      0    9408   79189   2212    2022 122504       0      0       0      0   >60    100%   48%  Fn   38%    0%     223      0   9185       0      0   75939      0
 74%      0      0      0   10978   92981   2651     572 147078       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   53%    0%      19      0  10959       0      0   89095      0
 67%      0      0      0   11839  101109   2946       8 148332       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   56%    0%       0      0  11839       0      0   96954      0
 64%      0      0      0   11517   98413   2899     256 138248       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   51%    0%       0      0  11517       0      0   94355      0
 62%      0      0      0   11653   99151   2920     559 106198       0      0       0      0   >60    100%   81%  :    40%    0%      52      0  11601       0      0   95030      0
 56%      0      0      0   11765   99752   2973     577   3009       0      0       0      0   >60    100%    3%  Fn    2%    0%     100      0  11665       0      0   95652      0
 82%      0      0      0    9987   85219   2327    1570 207259       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   60%    0%       5      0   9982       0      0   81692      0
 67%      0      0      0   11859  101347   2970       0 158696       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   57%    0%       0      0  11859
```

Into a 2D Array, so that I can take average of one of the column ,
Can someone let me know how it is done ?

My code:

```
preg_match('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'/is', $akshay_file, $match);
                            $text2 = nl2br($match[1]);
                            echo "$text2";
```

Can someone let me know how it is done, am I doing it the wrong way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are reading this from a file. As an option, read the file line by line and consider the following code

```
<?php
$n = "65%      0      0      0   11357   97020   2846       0 156160       0      0       0      0   >60    100%  100%  :f   45%    0%       3      0  11354       0      0   92987      0";
$n = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $n);
$parts = explode(' ', $n);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($parts, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should split the code in lines and then split each line by whitespaces.

```
$lines = preg_split('/$\R?^/m', $data);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $cols = preg_split('/\s\s+/', $data);
    // do sth..
}
```